# Android Tablet not found in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Windows 7 64bit and a Samsung Tab 3 10" with Android 4.2.2
The device is found by Windows and I can browse the folder. However Eclipse does not find the device. I refuse to install Kies on my computer and I did not find a driver alone?
I am a Newbee and would be greatful for any help!
THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Install Kies.  You can browse the file because it is currently detected as an external drive, not an Android device.

There may be a standalone driver out there somewhere.  Another alternative is to just jump ship from Windows and develop in OSX/Linux.  That way you don't need to worry about installing the drivers :)

Comment: Thanks - however Kies is what I wanted to avoid. With Ubuntu I had all kind of troubles where all my friends said - wow, never seen similar effects so finally I decided to stay with Windows...

Comment: Yeah, I understand wanting to avoid Kies.  However, that's how Samsung packages their drivers.  If you want to go snag a Nexus 10 or some other tablet, that is an alternative as well.  More costly of course.

Comment: What I finally did was to install Kies and uninstall it afterwards again. When uninstalling you have the choice to uninstall the drivers too or leave them. I chose to leave them on the PC and that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You need a driver for the tablet to be detected correctly. It can be downloaded as part of the Kies package here: http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Comment: Thanks. However this is SetupKies.exe - there is no driver alone. Kies caused so much trouble on one of my other PCs I'd rather want to avoid it here. Any idea how to get the driver alone?

Comment: I don't think you can anymore :( Try @Colombet Josselyn's method. If that does not work, you can always install Kies, but set it up to not run on startup on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Go in **devices manager**, you can see an **yellow triangle named "Android"**, **update drivers** and go into

**\adt\sdk\extras\google**

It's work for my SamSung Galaxy Tab2 !

forgive my bad english !

Comment: Sorry - did not fully understand. Device manager on my PC? I did not find the triangle there...

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did was to install Kies and uninstall it afterwards again. When uninstalling you have the choice to uninstall the drivers too or leave them. I chose to leave them on the PC and that did the job.